# Using multiple MQTT node-red nodes behaving not as expected

Tags: node.js, nodes, node-red

I have multiple MQTT nodes with different topics configured in them. Now I will process the value of multiple topics and figure out some assumptions(Basically stream analytics).

**My expectation:**

I know that java script is single threaded. So I thought that when one topic data is received it will be processed and then only once it is completed other topic will be received and so on.

**Reality:**

It is working like multi threaded.

**Test case:**

**Flow:** MQTT ---> Process for a second ---> Output

**Sleep function code(Not really sleeping more like processing):**

```
var start = new Date().getTime();
for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++)
{
    if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > 1000)
    {
      break;
    }
}
return msg;
```

Now I will publish data form 1 to 100 continuously using for loop.

**My expectation:**

Now 1, 2, 3....100 will be displayed one after another with 1 second gap. So now it should be taking 100 seconds approximately to display values form 1 to 100.

**Reality:**

*First it will sleep for 100 seconds and then form 1 to 100 all will be displayed at once. **So what is happening here?***

**Flow json:**

```
[{"id":"e9a53835.09af38","type":"tab","label":"Flow 1","disabled":false,"info":""},{"id":"5ffb1b40.1405b4","type":"debug","z":"e9a53835.09af38","name":"","active":true,"tosidebar":true,"console":false,"tostatus":false,"complete":"false","x":438,"y":216,"wires":[]},{"id":"a8406277.a78ee","type":"mqtt in","z":"e9a53835.09af38","name":"Test MQTT Queue","topic":"1","qos":"2","broker":"b4c58fab.26844","x":146,"y":120,"wires":[["629e90bb.996ad"]]},{"id":"629e90bb.996ad","type":"function","z":"e9a53835.09af38","name":"Sleep 1 seconds","func":"var start = new Date().getTime();\nfor (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++)\n{\n    if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > 1000)\n    {\n      break;\n    }\n}\nreturn msg;","outputs":1,"noerr":0,"x":298,"y":168,"wires":[["5ffb1b40.1405b4"]]},{"id":"b4c58fab.26844","type":"mqtt-broker","z":"","name":"","broker":"127.0.0.1","port":"1883","clientid":"","usetls":false,"compatmode":true,"keepalive":"60","cleansession":true,"willTopic":"","willQos":"2","willRetain":"false","willPayload":"","birthTopic":"","birthQos":"2","birthRetain":"false","birthPayload":""}]
```

**C# publisher function:**

```
// Retain: false, QOS= 2 on both publisher and client.
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
{
    client.Publish(1, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(i.ToString()), MqttMsgBase.QOS_LEVEL_EXACTLY_ONCE, false);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. The first message arrives and is passed to the Function node which then does a busy-wait loop, not allowing the node.js event loop to process any other work.
2. During that time, the remaining 99 messages arrive in the underlying MQTT client and internal events are queued up to process them
3. The first message then finally makes it to the Debug node. The Debug node passes the message to the websocket asynchronously - which means that piece of work is wrapped in an event and put at the end of the node.js event queue - behind the 99 messages.
4. the same then happens for the next 99 events - they are processed synchronously with no opporunity for the node.js event loop to make progress, each one added another event to the end of the queue to have the message passed to Debug
5. The last of the messages is processed, the node.js event loop then reaches the events to process the debug messages over the websocket and all 100 messages appear in the Debug sidebar

The key here is that blocking synchronously is a bad thing to do in the node.js world. If you want to delay a message, use a Delay node, which does so using timers - thereby allowing node.js to continue processing other work in the background.